# Inserir texto á uma textarea sem modificar o texto que já existe com input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea

Pessoal como inserir um texto a esta Textarea sem Modificar o valor que ja está dentro dela ao preencher os inputs?

eu tenho uma preview
https://jsfiddle.net/orpwmc5b/3

quando escrevo nos "input" ele apaga o valor pre-definido...

alguma maneira de adicionar sem remover ao preencher as input?

codigo html

```
<b>MEU NOME: </b>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="i1"><br>
<b>Cidade:</b>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="i2"><br>
<b>Estado:</b>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="i3"><br>
<b>Meu Bairro:</b>
<input type="text" name="company" id="i4">

<textarea id="i5">Texto predefinido que nao pode apagar</textarea>
```

Codigo Jquery javascript

```
<script>
$( function() {
    function updateTextarea() {
        $( '#i5' ).val( $( '#i1' ).val() + '\n\n' + $( '#i2' ).val() + '\n\n' + $( '#i3' ).val() + '\n\n' + $( '#i4' ).val() );
    }
    $( '#i1, #i2, #i3, #i4' ).keydown( updateTextarea );
});
</script>
```

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar uma variavel global para guardar o valor do `#i5` e concatenar como as outras... o evento tambem mudei para keyup.

```
var i5text =  $('#i5').val();

$(function() {
   function updateTextarea() {

        $('#i5').val(i5text + '\n\n' + $('#i1').val() + '\n\n' + $('#i2').val() + '\n\n' + $('#i3').val() + '\n\n' + $('#i4').val());
        }
        $('#i1, #i2, #i3, #i4').keyup(updateTextarea);
    });
```

Comment: Incrível ! me salvou ^^ MUIIIITOO OBRIGADO!